# Raspberry pi - can't install Python 3.11

Tags: raspberry-pi, repository

I am setting up a raspberry pi with OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), and it comes with 3.9.x and I need ver 3.11. Below is what I get when I add the repository (any suggestions what to do here?)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/bullseye
```

Answer (score 6):

Other than relying on APT repository `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, You can go ahead fetching the python 3.11 source code from the [python.org](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tgz) using wget

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tgz
```

Now install the build tools and git.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev git
```

Configure, make and install

```
tar -xzvf Python-3.11.4.tgz 
cd Python-3.11.4/
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

This will install Python 3.11 in your Raspberry but in order to make it default, you have to remove the link to `/usr/bin/python3` and link python3.11

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/bin/python
```

Check the python version by `python -VV`

> Python 3.11.4

Comment: Changing the default Python version could break some systems. I recommend to call it with `python3.11` and using virtualenv